# Turn off power to USB Port programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a project that I'm working on and I want to use these:
http://www.woot.com/blog/post/usb-powered-woot-off-lights-2

However it looks like they just have on/off switches. They aren't something that you can interface with programmatically.

So I was thinking, if I could find a way to cut the power to the USB port, that would allow me to turn the lights on and off with my app. However I cant find any way to cut the power to the USB port. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have admin privileges, then run the following:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 4, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: Which of these vars specifies which USB port I'm disabling? the 4?

Comment: This actually doesn't cut power to USB Ports but disables them for USB Storage Devices. And that too is not for a specific port, but for all ports. And the "4" here is the values for "Disable" and "3" for "Enable".

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and solved it using DevManView.exe (freeware):

1. Download DevManView.exe and put the .exe file somewhere:
   http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html
2. Go to your Device Manager and figure out which USB-Controller you have to enable/disable, so that your device does/doesn't get power anymore. For me disabling "USB Serial Converter" does cut the power of all USB slots.

[USB Serial Converter in device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8kpd.png)

3. In C#, create and start a new process for disabling the device (using the name of the USB-Controller).

   ```
   Process devManViewProc = new Process();
   devManViewProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"<path to DevManView.exe>\DevManView.exe";
   devManViewProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/disable \"USB Serial Converter\"";
   devManViewProc.Start();
   devManViewProc.WaitForExit();
   ```
4. And enable it again.

   ```
   devManViewProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/enable \"USB Serial Converter\"";
   devManViewProc.Start();
   devManViewProc.WaitForExit();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: unfortunately it seems the products from this company [are not sold anymore](https://www.tindie.com/stores/madeintheusb/items/).

---

The powered-woot-off-lights-2 are powered via a regular usb plug which mean they are 5 volts and there are in each one light and one motor.

I could not find how many Amps are needs but I know that this extension would be perfect if 200 mA for one powered-woot-off-lights is enough.

[USB Controler Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8z8N.jpg)

The C# or VB.NET code would look like this.

```
// On
nusbio.GPIOS[NusbioGpio.Gpio0].DigitalWrite(true);
nusbio.GPIOS[NusbioGpio.Gpio1].DigitalWrite(true);
// Off
nusbio.GPIOS[NusbioGpio.Gpio0].DigitalWrite(false);
nusbio.GPIOS[NusbioGpio.Gpio1].DigitalWrite(false);
```

see [Nusbio's website](http://madeintheusbwebsite.azurewebsites.net/) and I think the extension is in their store.
I used a similar nusbio extension myself.

[to turn on/off my a USB fan and a battery powered small lamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDKQY.jpg)