# PowerShell or C# - Turn off or "sleep" USB port without rebooting

Tags: c#, powershell, usb

I have a USB 2.0 LED backlit keyboard which continuously has it's LED's on.  Unfortunately, the only way to turn off  the LEDs is via hotkeys that require a special FN keyboard key (which isn't accessible via keybd_event API or sendkeys class).

Hence, I'd like to make a Powershell script which either disables or suspends/sleeps the USB port for the keyboard (without reboot) after the keyboard and/or mouse has been idle for 15 minutes or longer.

I know there's a USB selective suspend Windows power-saving feature; however, I'm not sure if I can manually do this via script/code for a specific USB port.  If it's not possible, I'm hoping for any other possible way to do something similar or just disable the port/device (without reboot).

I did some Internet searches; but the only thing I could find was how to disable the entire USB hub.

If this is something that can't be done easily via Powershell/Win32 API, then I would like to know how to do it via .NET/C#.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690157/turn-off-power-to-usb-port-programmatically

Comment: @SamFisher83 I think that would toggle all USB ports at once. Also I’m not sure if this would actually disable the power output on the USB ports.

Comment: Q: Is your goal to "disable the keyboard" ... or to "save power"? I believe the latter is a BIOS-level thing - I don't think you can really control it with either PowerShell or C#: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/311175-30-ports-shut-power

Comment: SamFisher83, I think I might not have been clear enough when I said all I could find was how to disable the entire USB hub (which is not what I want).  @Paulsm4, Im looking for any way to either disable the usb port or put the port in power saving mode.  They both would be a good attempt to disable the LED's on my keyboard.